# Angular4: HttpClient delete request

Tags: angular

I am new in angular 4. I use angular 4 and Laravel 5.5 and when I delete a post, the post is not deleted  and return to console 405 Method Not Allowed 
when I paste the link in Url,  the Post already deleted from the database
this is service[service .ts][Compentent.ts]

and the Component.ts is

```
deletePost(id:number){

return this.posts.deletePost(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
console.log("deleted")});

  }

}
```

and the service is

```
 deletePost(id:number){

    return this.http.delete('http://localhost/ajaxProject/public/api/delete/'+id)
    .map((response:Response)=>{return response.json().response});
 }
```

Comment: Did you try the same request with postman? You need that to configure the CORS on the server.

Comment: If you get a method not allowed when requesting via angular, but it works when you paste the delete url in the browser, it probably means that on laravel side the delete service is not configured for the `DELETE` http method, but rather for `GET`

Comment: yes the same thing with postman